# Views overwrite node - URL

Tags: views, path-aliases

I have node URL like:
http://url.com/program/category/app/

I would like to create view with path:
http://url.com/program/category/app/**alternatives**

Is this possible? When I use in Views. I tried 
"/program/%/%/alternatives"
but this doesnt work, run node not my views.